# genetic python algorithm to make the smallest set of words

Tags: python, genetic

I have a course in AI and I have an exercise to write a code producing the shortest possible sentence (in term of number of character) I have a list2D of departure
It's just word list no real english sentence.I do not need to have a correct sentence in English

```
data=[["One","Two","He","You","a"],["have","had","make","do"],["red","blue"]]
```

I have to make a sentence of 3 words as small as possible (in number of character), the solution for the example i presented before would be "a do red"

here is what I did in genetic algorithm, I seek the most value patite by modifying each gen 0.05% of the pop.

An individual is a sentence, A population is a phrase set , I try to generate the smallest possible sentence.

the problem is that the value does not change. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: English sentences start with a capital letter, require a verb and a subject.

Comment: yes i'm sorry, i edited, the solution is  "a do red"
And i have not need a correct sentence. It's just word list no real english sentence

Comment: "a do red" is not a valid English sentence either.

Comment: It's just word list no real english sentence.I do not need to have a correct sentence in English

Comment: try narrowing your problem down

Comment: I have 2D list word and i must found the small word (number of caractere) with use genetic algorithm
for example

data=[["One","Two","He","You","a"],["have","had","make","do"],["red","blue"]]

the solution is "a do red"

Answer (score 2):

If you have to pick one word from each list, you could do:

```
for sublist in data:
    print(min(sublist, key=len))

Out [4]:
a
do
red
```

Or if you want a single string as result:

```
" ".join([min(sublist, key=len) for sublist in data])

Out [2]:
'a do red'
```

Note that this picks the first shortest word from each list, so if there are multiple words with the shortest length you get whichever is first in your list. Rather than print them out you may want to append them to a new list, or do something else dependent on your use case.